# Problem making borders the same height as my div

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make the exact same navigation bar as the one on the screenshot but I have a problem doing it, I also have other lists in my page and it causes troubles.

Here's what I have done

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#anchor1">Partie 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor2">Partie 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor3">Partie 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor4">Partie 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Page]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Your question isn't too clear about what you need help with.

Comment: What's the problem, the height of your borders seem fine in your snippet.

Comment: Your borders exactly the same height as your div. You can see this in the developer console. Try to rephrase the task.

Comment: I want to make the same navigation bar as on the page (partie1, partie2 etc..) but I don't know how to do it..

Comment: if you have a border on the nav then you need to also use a clearfix. if everything inside is floating else the container wont know it exists - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ - I have never liked using `display:inline-block` as it does not work well for everything

Answer (score 1):

So it seems your real question was how to make your navigation look like the one in the picture.

To make this more clear I went ahead and added the border around the `#nav` element.

You should get rid of `float:left` and instead set your `li` to `display : inline-block`.

Then move the padding from the `a` tag to the `li` tag.

Then decrease the vertical padding to the desired height. I think this is enough to get the desired look.

> I also have other lists in my page and it causes troubles.

You should use classes and [css selectors](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/) then. Instead of just `ul` and `li` you should add classes to your elements and then select them in the css.

In the example below I simply selected them based on the root element that has the id `nav`. So now this css shouldn't effect anything else on your page.

```css
#nav {
  width : 100%;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
  display : inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#nav li a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#anchor1">Partie 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor2">Partie 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor3">Partie 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor4">Partie 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```